# Decomposition of an algebraic variety into irreducible components

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm studying the Fulton's algebraic curves book and I have the following doubts in the end of the page 9:

[image]

I didn't understand why the following equations hold:

> $$I\left(\bigcup_i V(F_i)\right)=\bigcap_i I(V(F_i))$$
>
> $$\bigcap_i (F_i)=(F_1\cdots F_r)$$

Thanks in advance

Comment: The first displayed equality is a tautology resulting from the definition of the $I$ operator (and you can even replace the $V(F_i)$'s by non-algebraic sets $S_i$ !) The second equality  is a souped-up version of the fact that an integer is divisible by $6$ if and only if it is divisible both by $2$ and $3$. Neither equality requires that $k$ be algebraically closed.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: = answer

Comment: @Martin:  I would prefer a more junior user to develop the comment into an actual answer, as an exercise in mathematical writing.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg:  Perhaps the OP, in fact.  OP, why not write up an answer to your own question (for posterity on this site)?

Comment: An excellent idea, @Sammy!

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg done :)

Answer (score 1):

### Equation 1:

> $$I\left(\bigcup_i V(F_i)\right)=\bigcap_i I(V(F_i))$$

Following the comments of the question, it's just a tautology:

**$\subset$ part**

$f\in I\left(\bigcup_i V(F_i)\right)\implies f(P)=0, \forall P\in \bigcup_i V(F_i)\implies f(P)=0,\forall P\in V(F_i)\ \text{for every i}\implies P\in I(V(F_i)),\ \text{for every i} \implies P\in \bigcap_i I(V(F_i))$

**$\supset$ part**

$f\in\bigcap_i I(V(F_i))\implies f\in I(V(F_i))\ \text{for every i}\implies f(P)=0\  \text{for}\ P\in V(F_i)\ \text{for every i}\implies f(P)=0\ \text{for}\ P\in \bigcup V(F_i)\implies f\in I\left(\bigcup_i V(F_i)\right)$

### Equation 2:

> $$\bigcap_i (F_i)=(F_1\cdots F_r)$$

**$\subset$ part**

For the case $r=2$: (the general case is similar)

Suppose $F_1, F_2$ are not associate:

$f\in (F_1)\cap (F_2)\implies f=g_1F_1=g_2F_2\implies F_1|g_2F_2\implies F_1|g_2$, the result follows.

(Note also that we use the fact that prime elements are irreducible and vice versa, because k[X,Y] is UFD)

**$\supset$ part**

Trivial